# Using the NetworkManager in Selenium Chromedriver breaks auth http proxy extensions

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I need to use a http proxy with auth in Selenium and AFAIK the only way to do this is via a custom extension at the moment. I have successfully tested this and it works fine (code below).

However it seems to fail if I attach a network listener like so:

```cs
NetworkManager manager = new NetworkManager(Driver);
manager.NetworkResponseReceived += NetworkResponseReceived;
await manager.StartMonitoring();
```

Whenever that code runs, all browsing attempts return a 407 unauthorized from I assume the proxy. Its as if the NetworkManager listener is maybe eating/intercepting the extension listener?

**Custom extension:**

```cs
    class ProxyExtension
    {
        private string _dir;
        private string manifestJson = @"
{
    ""version"": ""1.0.0"",
    ""manifest_version"": 2,
    ""name"": ""Chrome Proxy"",
    ""permissions"": [
        ""proxy"",
        ""tabs"",
        ""unlimitedStorage"",
        ""storage"",
        ""<all_urls>"",
        ""webRequest"",
        ""webRequestBlocking""
    ],
    ""background"": {""scripts"": [""background.js""]},
    ""minimum_chrome_version"": ""76.0.0""
}
";

        private string backgroundJsTemplate = @"
var config = {{
    mode: ""fixed_servers"",
    rules: {{
        singleProxy: {{
            scheme: ""http"",
            host: ""{0}"",
            port: {1}
        }},
        bypassList: [""localhost""]
    }}
}};

chrome.proxy.settings.set({{value: config, scope: ""regular""}}, function() {{}});

function callbackFn(details) {{
    return {{
        authCredentials: {{
            username: ""{2}"",
            password: ""{3}""
        }}
    }};
}}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
    callbackFn,
    {{ urls: [""<all_urls>""] }},
    ['blocking']
);
";

        public ProxyExtension(string host, int port, string user, string password)
        {
            _dir = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName());
            Directory.CreateDirectory(_dir);

            string manifestFile = Path.Combine(_dir, "manifest.json");
            File.WriteAllText(manifestFile, manifestJson);

            string backgroundJs = string.Format(backgroundJsTemplate, host, port, user, password);
            string backgroundFile = Path.Combine(_dir, "background.js");
            File.WriteAllText(backgroundFile, backgroundJs);
        }

        public string DirectoryPath
        {
            get { return _dir; }
        }

        ~ProxyExtension()
        {
            Directory.Delete(_dir, true);
        }
    }
```